# How to store logs in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, apache, logging, fluentd

I am using Fluentd data collector for storing Apache httpd logs in MongoDB. I made the necessary changes in td-agent configuration files like:

```
<source>
  @type tail

  format apache2

  path C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\logs\access.log

  tag mongo.apache
 </source>
```

and

```
<match mongo.**>
  # plugin type

  @type mongo

  # mongodb db + collection

  database apache

  collection access


  # mongodb host + port

  host localhost

  port 27017


  # interval

  flush_interval 10s

  # make sure to include the time key

  include_time_key true

</match>
```

After doing all necessary changes, I tested configurations by pinging Apache server

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://localhost/
```

Everything works fine, but the logs files were not stored in MongoDB.

I did this in windows.